# Unable to Export Data in Toad for Oracle

Tags: oracle, export, toad

My Toad for Oracle recently updated to version 14 and since then I have been having an issue with exporting data. This applies to data sets that are a few thousand records as well as results with few million records.

In other words I'm currently attempting to export a data set with around 50k rows however when I try to export it, I get the following error message

**Qry: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset**

I also, get the above error when trying to skip to the last row of the results using toad but that also doesn't work.

I never had this issue in the past and was able to export as many rows as I wanted. Is there some sort of setting which I need to enable in Toad to allow this. I have a coworker who is able to export the data using the same query results so I'm not sure why is it specifically me that is having this issue.

Comment: The latest version is 15 (can you upgrade?). Which version does your coworker use?

Comment: I cannot update to 15 since our updates are first tested and approved by our organization and then pushed through for the rest of the employees to upgrade through software center.......My Coworker has the older version 12 which I do as well but on his end it works but on mine it does not......To clarify, I have Toad for Oracle version 12 and 14 as well as Toad Data Point and on all three of those I am getting the same error.

Comment: Google doesn't return much; there are problems reported, but none for exporting data. It says that such an error appears when your session "expires", but I guess that you didn't run query "yesterday" and tried to export data "today morning", did you? Perhaps you should ask the question on ToadWorld Forum (https://forums.toadworld.com/c/toad-for-oracle/10)

Comment: you are correct, I run the query and try to export it right away. The interesting thing is that after I get the error message, it shows my session as disconnected however I am still able to run the same queries and others while it supposedly is disconnected. But for good measure, I reconnect my session and the problem persists

Comment: That really sounds like the problem (you being disconnected; that's what they call the "closed dataset"), but I wouldn't know *why* you're disconnected. Is your user assigned a profile whose settings say that session lasts "short", or something like that?